# DataTable not formatting datetime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, datatables

I have a datatable with `id = 'att_tm_req'`. It contains date in first column in the format

```
2018-09-06 16:04:00 UTC
```

I want to show it in the format `DD/MM/YYY` with the month name in English instead of numerical `MM` representation.

When I apply the following `js` to my table:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {

    $('#att_tm_req').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
          targets: 0,
          render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'Do DD MMM YYYYY' )
        } ]
    } );
});
```

The datatable shows :

```
Invalid date
```

on every row which used to be perfectly fine data. 
I already have the `moment.js` file added to my `application.js`.
Open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) **cant define your source date time format**.

Your datetime format is:

**YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss UTC**

Then you need to use two (2) parameter of [DataRender Datetime plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime) and [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) which is:

> $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( from, to );

And your code should replaced like this:

```
columnDefs: [{
            targets: 1,
            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss UTC','Do DD MMM YYYYY')
            }]
```

**Example Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#example').DataTable({
 columnDefs: [{
       targets: 1,
       render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss UTC','Do DD MMM YYYYY')
     }]
   });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date Before</th>
      <th>Date After</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-09-06 16:04:00 UTC</td>
      <td>2018-09-06 16:04:00 UTC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!